# Main thread doing too much work because of asynchronous Firebase calls?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, firebase

I keep getting an error on my application that says `I/Choreographer: Skipped 252 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` I think this causes some lag on my UI which I don't want. I think it is because when I perform a Firebase query, when I do `onDataChange()`, it seems to be always executed in the main UI Thread. I have around 5 Firebase queries similar to what I have below. As a result, I tried to move my code from `onDataChange()` method to an `AsyncTask` and update the UI thread on `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask`. However, when I try this, the `onPostExecute()` method never completes. Here is my attempt:

```
public void getPublicPosts(final View progressOverlay, final View fragmentView, final Context context) {
    //Need to do order by / equal to.
    Firebase postsRef = firebaseRef.child("Posts");
    Query query = postsRef.orderByChild("privacy").equalTo("Public");
    query.keepSynced(true);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (final DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) {
                        Post post = postSnapShot.getValue(Post.class);
                        List<Post> publicPosts = application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts();
                        if (post.getPrivacy().equals("Public") && application.getPublicAdapter().containsId(publicPosts, post.getId()) == null) {
                            application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts().add(0, post);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
                        System.out.println("Finished executing public");
                        populateNewsFeedList(fragmentView, application.getPublicAdapter(), TabEnum.Public, context);
                        if (progressOverlay.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            System.out.println("getPublicPosts: DONE");
                            AndroidUtils.animateView(progressOverlay, View.GONE, 0, 200);
                            fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_public_feed).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                };
                `task.execute();`
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Any help with this would be helpful. If anyone could help me out that would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: Adding in Function to create `AsyncTask`

```
public AsyncTask asyncTaskWrapper(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, final View progressOverlay, final View fragmentView, final Context context) {
        AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>() {
            @Override
            protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) {
                for (final DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = postSnapShot.getValue(Post.class);
                    List<Post> publicPosts = application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts();
                    if (post.getPrivacy() == PrivacyEnum.Public && application.getPublicAdapter().containsId(publicPosts, post.getId()) == null) {
                        application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts().add(0, post);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
                System.out.println("Finished executing public");
                TabsUtil.populateNewsFeedList(fragmentView, application.getPublicAdapter(), TabEnum.Public, context);
                if (progressOverlay.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    System.out.println("getPublicPosts: GONE");
                    AndroidUtils.animateView(progressOverlay, View.GONE, 0, 200);
                    fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_public_feed).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        };
        return task;
    }
```

PublicPosts function:

```
public void getPublicPosts(final View progressOverlay, final View fragmentView, final Context context) {
    //Need to do order by / equal to.
    Firebase postsRef = firebaseRef.child("Posts");
    Query query = postsRef.orderByChild("privacy").equalTo(PrivacyEnum.Public.toString());
    query.keepSynced(true);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            asyncTaskWrapper(dataSnapshot, progressOverlay, fragmentView, context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            TabsUtil.populateNewsFeedList(fragmentView, application.getPublicAdapter(), TabEnum.Public, context);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of implementing AsyncTask inside for loop, define it separately and then execute it from for loop, so it will run on another thread safely.

Comment: @Vickyexpert Hi, I understand what you are trying to say but I can't seem to figure out a way to instantiate `AsyncTask` once without recreating it multiple times. I have posted my attempt in the original post.

Comment: What is application.getPublicAdapter()?? I think one reason for frame skipping may be that application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts().add(0, post) is triggering notifyDataSetChanged multiple times.

This might also be the reason that your application exits as notifyDataSetChanged cannot be called in background thread.

Comment: ¿ It is necessary for you to show progress in the main thread ?. I think Asynctask only executes in background on doInBackground() function. So, it will be more efficient thread and handler system.

Answer (score 3):

Your main thread is probably slow because you are running a loop with many objects. However, not knowing what exactly you are executing, that is just a guess.

But I a problem with your AsyncTask, I don't think it will ever work with the code you posted.

The AsyncTask is expecting an array of URLs. You are not passing any. If don't need URLs as input, then just use:

```
AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean>()
```

How about you try for troubleshooting:

```
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<URL, Boolean, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... params) {
            for (final DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Post post = postSnapShot.getValue(Post.class);
                List<Post> publicPosts = application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts();
                if (post.getPrivacy() == PrivacyEnum.Public && application.getPublicAdapter().containsId(publicPosts, post.getId()) == null) {
                    application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts().add(0, post);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(result){
                System.out.println("Finished executing public");
                TabsUtil.populateNewsFeedList(fragmentView, application.getPublicAdapter(), TabEnum.Public, context);
                if (progressOverlay.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    System.out.println("getPublicPosts: GONE");
                    AndroidUtils.animateView(progressOverlay, View.GONE, 0, 200);
                    fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_public_feed).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Then execute the task by firing:

```
URL[] urls = new URL[2];
urls[0] = new URL(...);
urls[1] = new URL(...);
task.execute(urls);
```

Use the debug feature in the IDE and post back the exact place if the code fails.

Answer (score 1):

you are not calling execute() on the AsyncTask you created so it will never be fired.

After creating you AsyncTask, call execute(URL... params) on it so it will get executed.

Also I see you are not using the params you are passing, so you can just pass nothing and it will work.

Comment: Hm, I called `execute()` after the creation of the `AsyncTask` but my application just exits now. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

You better do network requests on IntentService. It´s easy and prevent interface freezing and/or "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread".

Take a look at:

[IntentService on Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are calling the AsynTast n time better you should call it once The for: each loop used to should be inside the doinbackground() and in onProgressUpdate() you can update the UI instead of onPostExecute(), this will improve the code little bit but not completely, you should use a progressbar on onPreexecute and dismiss the progressbar at onPostEcecute(), just for your idea I have the write the bellow code, but don't refer it completely as i have not tested this, but form this will get some idea.

```
AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>() {
                @Override
                protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) { 
for (final DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = postSnapShot.getValue(Post.class);
                    List<Post> publicPosts = application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts();
                    if (post.getPrivacy().equals("Public") && application.getPublicAdapter().containsId(publicPosts, post.getId()) == null) {
                        application.getPublicAdapter().getPosts().add(0, post);
                    }
              publishProgress((1);
      }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                  System.out.println("Finished executing public");
                populateNewsFeedList(fragmentView, application.getPublicAdapter(), TabEnum.Public, context);
                if (progressOverlay.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    System.out.println("getPublicPosts: DONE");
                    AndroidUtils.animateView(progressOverlay, View.GONE, 0, 200);
                    fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_public_feed).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Hey I tried to follow what you suggested but that didn't work well unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been much cleaner and easier to maintain if you have created a class that extends an AsyncTask and call it like this in your ondatachange method:

```
DoingStuff doTask = new DoingStuff();
doTask.execute(...);
```

This way you safely execute your Firebase connection stuff in a worker thread and update your UI with whatever results you have retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of the following:

- Instead of creating and executing multiple N AsyncTasks, just create and execute a single one with the N snapshots loop inside.
- In onPostExecute() check that **populateNewsFeedList** method is not doing intensive data manipulations, if so you can execute it in a new AsyncTask too and update the UI after it finishes.
- You can also try updating the views by passing a runnable to the [post](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method, this will enqueue the runnables in the main thread message queue.
- You can run your long running operations in a **Service** or an **IntentService** and update your UI via a **ContentProvider** or **Broadcasts**.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Remove the heavy work from the UI main thread, excutes them in the other threads.

2.When the other threads finish the heavy work, if it need to update the UI, use Handler to send the msg to UI main thread, and then update the UI on main thread.